# <_UIPopoverBackgroundVisualEffectView> is being asked to animate its opacity

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

I am trying to show an (AlertController) Action sheet. But I am getting this waning in console  " <_UIPopoverBackgroundVisualEffectView 0x7fd65ef76ec0> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1. "

here is my code :-

```
extension GroupDataView {

  func callDot (sender : UIButton)
  {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil,
                                  preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Group", style: .default , handler:{ (action)in
        print("User click Edit Group")
      }))

      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Create Folder", style: .default , handler:{ (action)in
        print("User click Create Folder button")
      }))

      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Group", style: .destructive , handler:{ (action)in
          print("User click Delete Group button")

      }))

        if let popoverController = alert.popoverPresentationController   {
          popoverController.sourceView = sender
          popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds

          self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
            print("completion block")
          })
       }

      else
      {
          self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
              print("completion block")
          })
      }
  }
}
```

I don't know why this warning is showing in console.
ActionSheet is coming properly but how to remove that warning?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

#### iOS Bug

See answer by [@Hardy](https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/Hardy) on Apple Developer Forum: **[Warning message from UIPopover](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53677)** <sup>†</sup>

> ... seems to be a bug in iOS. But it does not seem to be critical. Though - I believe - that sometimes the area below the UIAlertController is not correctly drawn.  I can see for a short period of time a black background flashing although the background of the underlying view is not black.

<sup>†</sup> Cached on Google [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MX9B44O8CIkJ:https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53677%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how to resolve it. I tried it.
Thanks

Comment: The original page seems to be revived from death

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I resolved it by setting `animated: false` in `self.present` or/and `self.dismiss` function. See the last comment in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53677

Answer (score -1):

I realise this is an old question but I was just faced with the same issue and I found a workaround by delaying the presentation by 0.001 seconds so when you normally call this function I used this code for the delay

```
[self performSelector:@selector(viewBookmark:) withObject:bookmarkBarButton afterDelay:0.001];
```

Please excuse the OBJ-C but a similar delay in swift should have the same result of not displaying 2 views at the same time.