# How to dismiss popover in swift on button clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I have created popover in which there are two buttons. I want to dismiss popover when button inside popover is clicked.

This is my code:
FirstViewController :

```
 @IBAction func bar_button(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as!
    SecondViewController
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200,height:80)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

    let popover = navController.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.delegate = self
    popover?.barButtonItem = sender as! UIBarButtonItem
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

SecondViewController :

```
@IBAction func second_button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //want to dismiss popover when button clicked
      }
@IBAction func second_button(_ sender: UIButton) {
   //want to dismiss popover when button clicked
      }
```

Answer (score 6):

Call

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

inside those methods, This will dismiss the presented popover.

Comment: But after doing that it gives this warning - UIPopoverBackgroundVisualEffectView is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.

Comment: @Abhishek: This issue has been addressed in the following answers briefly, have a look at and let me know if it resolves your issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589946/uipopoverbackgroundvisualeffectview-is-being-asked-to-animate-its-opacity